# Generating random background colour of nth child link in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have around 55 links in html, all the links having same link text namely *"Buy"*. Now in JavaScript, I wanted to randomize the background colour of the links using the following code. It's not working. I checked the page with and without jQuery introduced in the page.

What's wrong with the code? How to do it?

```
var num;
var arbt = ["yellow", "green", "blue", "magenta", "red", "white", "lime"];

for (num = 0; num < 55; num++) {
    var ran = Math.floor(Math.random * (arbt.length + 1));
    var colo = arbt[ran];

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a:nth-child(num)").css("background-color", colo);
    });
}
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Can you show some of your html? Create a fiddle is the best idea

Comment: you have missed out, concatinating your num variable..

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I use codepen.io - kinda same as jsfiddle. you can see this pen [here](http://codepen.io/petronav/pen/XXZPKY)

Comment: @michaelpetronav Added answer that works as it should and added pen

Answer (score 3):

change document ready function to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a:nth-child(" + num + ")").css("background-color", colo);
});
```

basically `num` is a variable, so change `a:nth-child(num)` to `a:nth-child(" + num + ")`

or simply make it

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").each( function(){
        var ran = Math.floor(Math.random * (arbt.length + 1));
        $( this ).css("background-color", arbt[ran] );
    } );
});
```

Comment: `:nth-child` selector begins at index `1`

Comment: @guest271314 I know, I don't it is even required so removed it :)

Answer (score 3):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function  () {
  var num;
  var arbt=["yellow","green","blue","magenta","red","white","lime"];
  jQuery("a").each(function (index) { //incase if you want to use index
    var ran = Math.floor(Math.random * (arbt.length + 1));
    var colo = arbt[ran];
    jQuery(this).css('background-color', colo);
  }) 

} )
```

Comment: the comment by @ameenulla0007 identifies the problem with your code but this answer is quite a bit more efficient than what you wrote originally.

Comment: except that you'll want to use `var ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * arbt.length));` otherwise you'll occasionally get out of range errors.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, this works:

```
$(document).ready(function  () {
  var num;
  var arbt=["yellow","green","blue","magenta","red","white","lime"];
  $("a").each(function (index) {
    var ran = Math.floor((Math.random() * arbt.length) + 1);
    var colo = arbt[ran];
    $(this).css('background-color', colo);
  }) 
})
```

[Here's a fork of your codepen](http://codepen.io/DS777/pen/jWZQzq)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than concatenating variables into the selector you can use `eq()` which will allow a variable directly and also starts at zero based index

```
$("a").eq(num).css("background-color", colo);
```